# undo git remote add upstream?

Tags: git, github

I have a directory structure similar to the following:

```
~/workspace/
  -- proj1/
  -- proj2/
```

proj1 and proj2 are git repos for different jobs.  Today I wanted to add another project, so I forked it on GitHub then cloned my fork locally.  That all went well, but then I wanted to add the upstream remote so I could sync my fork later on.
Without thinking I ran

```
git remote add upstream <upstream:url>
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

from the ~/workspaces directory.
This added the upstream repo's content to the ~/workspaces directory. It left the proj folders un-touched, which is nice.
I deleted all of the accidentally added files from workspaces and got everything setup how I originally intended, but now if I run `git log` from ~/workspaces I get the history of the upstream repo.

What is the best way to stop git from thinking ~/workspaces is a repo?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming everything was clean when you did the `git merge`, you can simply `git reset --hard HEAD^` to un-do the merge, and `git remote remove upstream` to delete the remote and all the `upstream/*` remote branches.

(The commits you picked up by doing `git fetch upstream` plus the merge will still be in your repository, but aside from occupying disk space they should be harmless.  Eventually, with no references remaining, they will be garbage-collected.)

Remember, while `git merge` does a lot of work in the working directory to get there, in the end, in terms of the repository, all it does is make a new commit that has, as its first parent, the previous tip of the branch you were on, and as the rest of its parents, the tip(s) of the branch(es) you merged:<sup>1</sup>

```
before merge:
...--o--o--T     <-- HEAD=your-branch

...--o--o--o     <-- upstream/master

after merge:
...--o--o--T
            \
             M   <-- HEAD=your-branch
            /
...--o--o--o     <-- upstream/master
```

where `T` is your previous branch-tip and `M` is the merge commit.  The name `HEAD^` means "find the tip of the current branch"—that's commit `M`—"and back up to its first parent": that's commit `T`, by the definition of a merge.  Then, `git reset --hard <sha-or-other-identifier>` tells git to do two things:

1. Change the current branch tip to point to the given commit.  In this case, that means: set the tip of `your-branch` to point to commit `T`.
2. Clean out working directory to make it look like the given commit (the `--hard` part of `git reset`).

Step 1 makes the commit graph look like this:

```
...--o--o--T     <-- HEAD=your-branch
            \
             M   [abandoned]
            /
...--o--o--o     <-- upstream/master
```

Once this is done, merge commit `M` remains in the repository but has no branch or other label pointing to it,<sup>2</sup> so is what I like to call "abandoned".  It will really be gone about 30 days later when the reflog entry expires and the commit gets garbage-collected.  If you've also deleted `upstream/master` by then, garbage-collecting `M` causes the entire lower chain of commits also to become collected as well, and you get all your disk space back.

---

<sup>1</sup>And of course, as its "tree", the merge commit has the working-directory contents after the merge.

<sup>2</sup>The way I mean labels, reflog entries are not labels themselves.  They act as temporary references; they last for 30 to 90 days by default, with the expiry time controlled by two configuration items.  The shorter (30 day) expiry applies to reflog entries that point to commits that are *not* reachable from the tip to which the corresponding reference points.

The above is complicated, but it means, for instance, that if you're on branch `devel` and you make some commits, those commits go into the `devel` reflog.  Say you make four commits, then `git reset --hard HEAD^` to "undo" the last one.  The tip of branch `devel` now points to your third commit.  The third commit points to your second, and your second points to your first.  Those three reflog entries are now considered "more valuable" than the one for the fourth commit: if you start from the commit `devel` names, you can't move forward to the fourth commit, only backward.

So, three of those reflog entries will stick around for 90 days, or whatever value is in `gc.reflogexpire` in your config.  The fourth one will only stick around for 30 days, or whatever value is in `gc.reflogexpireunreachable`.

I've just noticed that newer versions of git (which ones?) augment this with `gc.pattern.reflogexpire` and `gc.ref.reflogexpireunreachable`.  This means, for instance, that you can set `gc.refs/stash.reflogexpireunreachable` to keep "up-level" stashes, like `stash@{2}`, around longer than the default 30 days, without keeping other reflog entries for longer periods.

Comment: Awesome!  Works great and +1 for the detail